# Add online video to 'textmedia' element

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In an extension, I would basically like to do what the core does when you click the button "Add media by URL" on an existing *textmedia* element.

[image]

I tried to look in the source code but did not find any convenient API function I could use. Perhaps I could use [DataHandler](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html#commands-array) for this?

What the core does is create a textfile (e.g. .youtube) which contains the video id. It then creates a record for this file in sys_file and a file reference (sys_file_reference) between the record in tt_content and the file record in sys_file.

---

I am using the latest TYPO3 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution, but I recently had to do something similar:

**Create a file from the Video URL and create the corresponding sys_file record:**

1. The class [OnlineMediaController::createAction](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9bc120c85e7156922b4077a11914e6735bcf7f5d/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/OnlineMediaController.php#L39) does what you are looking for. Specifically, the function [OnlineMediaHelperRegistry::transformUrlToFile](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/cb67c1e02e666be5ddd5c4b6fd5054814253591b/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/OnlineMedia/Helpers/OnlineMediaHelperRegistry.php#L59) will transform the video URL to a file (creating it if necessary).
2. To use the existing action, you can use the Ajax Route [online_media_create](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9bc120c85e7156922b4077a11914e6735bcf7f5d/typo3/sysext/backend/Configuration/Backend/AjaxRoutes.php#L202).
3. Or, you can use the existing action to model your own code.

**Create a relation between existing records in sys_file and tt_content:**

1. See [Creating a file reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#creating-a-file-reference) (TYPO3 documentation)

**Sample code:** (Most of the code taken from [Creating a file reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#creating-a-file-reference))

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\OnlineMedia\Helpers\OnlineMediaHelperRegistry;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility;
```

...

```
protected function addMediaByUrl($url, $uid)
{
    $targetFolder = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->getDefaultUploadFolder();
    $file = OnlineMediaHelperRegistry::getInstance()->transformUrlToFile(
        $url, 
        $targetFolder
    );
    $contentElement = BackendUtility::getRecord('tt_content', $uid);
    $newId = 'NEW1234';
    $data = array();
    $data['sys_file_reference'][$newId] = [
        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
        'uid_local' => $file->getUid(),
        'tablenames' => 'tt_content',
        'uid_foreign' => $contentElement['uid'],
        'fieldname' => 'assets',
        'pid' => $contentElement['pid']
    ];
    $data['tt_content'][$contentElement['uid']] = [
        'assets' => $newId
    ];
    // Get an instance of the DataHandler and process the data
    /** @var DataHandler $dataHandler */
    $dataHandler = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataHandler::class);
    $dataHandler->start($data, array());
    $dataHandler->process_datamap();
    // Error or success reporting
    if (count($dataHandler->errorLog) === 0) {
        // Handle success
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you look here for good examples
[YoutubeVideo](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Media/YoutubeViewHelper.html), [Vimeo](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Media/VimeoViewHelper.html), [Video-Files](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Media/VideoViewHelper.html), More Informations you can find at the vhs [Docs](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/)

Or you could do something like this:

```html
<flux:form id="youtubevideo" label="YouTubeVideo" description="Einbetten eines 
YouTube Videos als iframe">
  <flux:form.option name="optionsettings">
    <flux:form.option.group value="Content" />
    <flux:form.option.icon
    value="EXT:extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/YouTubeVideo.svg" />
  </flux:form.option>

  <flux:field.input name="settings.videoid" label="YouTube Video ID. Entnehmen 
  Sie die ID aus der YouTube URL. Beispiel: https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
  v=UX12345678 Die ID ist UX12345678" />
  <flux:field.select name="settings.videoformat" label="Video Format"
  maxItems="1" multiple="0" default="YouTubeVideo--normal" items="{YouTubeVideo-- 
  normal: 'Normal (4:3)', YouTubeVideo--widescreen: 'Widescreen (16:9)'}"/>
  <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.gridPull" label="Bleed Outside (Randlos 
  glücklich)" default="0" />
</flux:form>

...

<div class="YouTubeVideo {settings.videoformat}">
  <iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube- 
  nocookie.com/embed/{settings.videoid}?rel=0&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough in my question: I don't want to embed a YouTube video somewhere on the page (though essentially that will be the result). I am writing a migration script for old, no longer supported content elements which contain a URL to a YouTube video. I wish to convert the content element to a 'textmedia' with a reference to the video. The end result should be the same as after someone created a 'textmedia' and added the URL with "Add media by URL". Your answer is interesting, but I don't think it answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

The key is to set the correct "**allowed extensions**": add "youtube" or "vimeo".
This will automatically add the missing "Add media by URL" button.

Example using Flux Inline FAL:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="myCustomVideoContentElement">
        <flux:field.inline.fal name="settings.records" label="video"
         multiple="false" minItems="1" maxItems="1"
         allowedExtensions="mp4,mkv,youtube,vimeo"
        />
    </flux:form>
</f:section>
```

(Typo3 9.5)

Comment: Note: flux is not part of TYPO3 core. Anyhow. Looks like a nice solution, I will check it out. Thanks!